# What is the difference between ferritin and hemoglobin?

Tags: human-biology, hematology, blood-circulation

I have been reading that ferritin is the store of iron but hemoglobin is actually the amount of this in blood.

Does hemoglobin get sourced from ferritin? Is it possible for a person to be low on ferritin but normal on hemoglobin? Will he feel any symptoms of anaemia, if so?

Answer (score -1):

> Does hemoglobin get sourced from ferritin?

Yes, of course it is. Ferritin is the superior Group.

> Is it possible for a person to be low on ferritin but normal on
>   hemoglobin?

Yes, since these things don't have something in common.

> Will he feel any symptoms of anaemia, if so?
>   Why should he?? No, he won't get any crazy feelings from this.

Comment: Please do add some references